# Google Scholar - Add article manually and merge?

Tags: publications, google-scholar, preprint

Three months earlier, I published a preprint version of my paper and it appeared immediately on my Google Scholar account.

Recently, I published my paper in a journal. However, this citation/version has not been on Google Scholar. Thus, only the old preprint version is available on my profile.

Can I manually add an article with the journal citation and then merge it with the preprint version? If my paper get any citations, would these citations appear on my Google Scholar profile?

Comment: How long have you waited? Often patience will resolve this problem without further effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do what you suggest, but a simpler solution would be to simply **edit the entry in your profile with the correct details** (journal name, page numbers, date, etc.). If Google Scholar later creates a separate entry because it did not realize that the two are the same, you can do the merge at that time.

If Google Scholar correctly recognizes your paper's journal and preprint version as the same paper, then (usually) citations should automatically get added to the existing entry.

Comment: If google scholar do not create a separate entry later, with this edit will my citations count ?

Comment: @AndreasKontogiannis Usually, yes, it should. If it does not, then usually Google Scholar would have created a separate version of the paper, which you may need to find and merge. None of this can be 100% guaranteed, since it is automated and does fail occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

You can [manually add an article](https://answers.library.westernsydney.edu.au/faq/196423) to Google Scholar.

> To add publications, click on the + button and select from the list of the following options:

> c) Add article manually: If the article cannot be found you can create an entry manually. First choose the publication type at the top of the form then fill in as many fields as possible

Then, you can [merge the manually-added article with the preprint](https://guides.library.tulsacc.edu/c.php?g=118408&p=770550).

> Select both versions of the article. Next, choose the "Merge" option from the Actions menu. You will then see both citations for the article listed. Click "Select" next to the best citation to the article (you can edit it later if you wish). This will merge the two versions.

Whether or not the citations will be counted is a question only Google can answer.

Comment: If I edit the current publication on Google Scholar, changing to the journal's name, would the citations count ?

Comment: In my experience, Google has separate entries for preprint versions. Thus, if you merge them yourself, it will count citations for either (to preprint or journal version) but if a paper cites both your preprint and paper, it will only count as one citation. Merging both versions so there's only one citation count is the way I usually do it; that way the information about the preprint is not lost in the editing of the entry.